# How to combine haskell pattern matches efficiently

Tags: haskell, optimization, pattern-matching, ghc

Say I have a bunch of functions with the type `Action -> Int -> Int` (or equivalent), where `Action` is a sum type, and each function only does real work with only one of the variants.

```
data Action = Reset | Increment | Decrement

tryReset :: Action -> Int -> Int
tryReset a i = case a of
  Reset -> 0
  _ -> i

tryIncrement :: Action -> Int -> Int
tryIncrement a i = case a of
  Increment -> i + 1
  _ -> i

tryDecrement :: Action -> Int -> Int
tryDecrement a i = case a of
  Decrement -> i - 1
  _ -> i
```

Is there a way to compose the functions (eg. like `composedTogether`) to result in a single case expression (`optimisedCase`), instead of the multiple case expressions (`multipleCase`)?

```
composedTogether :: Action -> Int -> Int
composedTogether a = tryReset a . tryIncrement a . tryDecrement a

optimisedCase :: Action -> Int -> Int
optimisedCase Reset i = 0
optimisedCase Increment i = i + 1
optimisedCase Decrement i = i - 1

multipleCase :: Action -> Int -> Int
multipleCase a i = case a of
  Decrement -> i - 1
  _ -> case a of
    Increment -> i + 1
    _ -> case a of
      Reset -> 0
      _ -> i
```

Or is ghc already magical and optimises this automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't underestimate the GHC optimiser. This is the result of `ghc -ddump-simpl -O2` (GHC 7.10.1 here)

```
composedTogether =
  \ (a_aoc :: Action) (eta_B1 :: Int) ->
    case a_aoc of _ [Occ=Dead] {
      Reset -> Optimization.composedTogether1;
      Increment ->
        case eta_B1 of _ [Occ=Dead] { GHC.Types.I# x_ayY ->
        GHC.Types.I# (GHC.Prim.+# x_ayY 1)
        };
      Decrement ->
        case eta_B1 of _ [Occ=Dead] { GHC.Types.I# x_ayN ->
        GHC.Types.I# (GHC.Prim.-# x_ayN 1)
        }
    }
```

As you can see, everything got inlined.

To get that, I had to *comment out* your `optimisedCase`. Otherwise, I got

```
composedTogether :: Action -> Int -> Int
composedTogether = optimisedCase

multipleCase :: Action -> Int -> Int
multipleCase = optimisedCase
```

since the GHC spotted the equivalent versions.

My advice is: forget about these micro optimizations, turn on `-O2`, and let the compiler do its job.

That being said, don't overestimate what the optimiser can do, too! :-P When it does matter, check the generated Core.

Comment: Sometimes the optimizer does too much! It took me over an hour the other day to figure out how to prevent GHC from allocating a thunk to get sharing that I didn't need when I wanted no allocation!

Answer (score 0):

```
optimisedCase :: Action -> Int -> Int
optimisedCase Reset i = 0
optimisedCase Increment i = i + 1
optimisedCase Decrement i = i - 1
```

is the preferred notation and much cleaner (which is equivalent to the case syntax)

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit my question to show the preferred notation.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is not the answer I was looking for. I was looking for a way to combine the functions `tryReset`, `tryIncrement` and `tryDecrement` using combinators (e.g. function composition) to result in efficient code; instead of manually writing the efficient code.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this a bit. I think this is possible if I use a church-encoded version of `Action`.

```
import Data.Monoid (Endo(..))

data Action' a = Action'
  { onReset :: a
  , onIncrement :: a
  , onDecrement :: a
  }

instance Functor Action' where
  fmap f a = Action' (f $ onReset a) (f $ onIncrement a) (f $ onDecrement a)

tryReset' :: Action' (Endo Int)
tryReset' = Action' (Endo $ const 0) mempty mempty

tryIncrement' :: Action' (Endo Int)
tryIncrement' = Action' mempty (Endo succ) mempty

tryDecrement' :: Action' (Endo Int)
tryDecrement' = Action' mempty mempty (Endo pred)

composeAction' :: Monoid a => Action' a -> Action' a -> Action' a
composeAction' x y = Action'
  (onReset x `mappend` onReset y)
  (onIncrement x `mappend` onIncrement y)
  (onDecrement x `mappend`  onDecrement y)

composedTogether' :: Action' (Endo Int)
composedTogether' = tryReset'
  `composeAction'` tryIncrement'
  `composeAction'` tryDecrement'

action :: Action' a -> Action -> a
action a Reset = onReset a
action a Increment = onIncrement a
action a Decrement = onDecrement a

doComposedTogether' :: Action -> Int -> Int
doComposedTogether' = action (appEndo <$> composedTogether')
```

My next question is: Is this the best way of doing this? Is there already an existing library that does this? Prisms?